# collection hook not called on second application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections, meteor-collection-hooks

I have an application written with Meteor 1.4 and run it on port 3000 (called A) know I want use A application database in another application (called B). In B console I set MONGO_URL like this:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor
```

And then run that on port 5000.
I have some [collection hook](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) on app A and also some collection hook on app B but hooks only called in app A.

For example in A we have:

```
collections.notes.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
    console.log("notes updated in A hook");
    console.log(doc);
}
```

And in B we have:

```
collections.notes.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
    console.log("notes updated in B hook");
    console.log(doc);
}
```

But it's only log `notes updated in A hook`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection hook runs only in the application where the change was made. Your app B hook won't run on a change from app A.

If you want to do something in app B based on the underlying MongoDB data changing then you want to [observe](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe) that collection:

```
collections.notes.find().observe({
  changed(newDocument, oldDocument){
    console.log('Notes changed! Old doc: '+oldDocument+' to '+newDocument);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hooks are identical. Clearly collection hooks only supports one hook per event.

Why do you want two identical callbacks?

Comment: I need to override `after hook` in app B.